# Trouble translating small C# "Random String" function to Haskell

Tags: c#, string, linq, haskell, random

I saw the following code in my companies codebase and thought to myself "Damn that's a fine line of linq, I'd like to translate that to Haskell to see what it's like in an actual functional language"

```
static Random random = new Random();
static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
                                .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                                .ToArray());
}
```

However I'm having a bit of trouble getting a concise and direct translation to Haskell because of how awkward it is to generate random numbers in this language.

I've considered a couple of approaches. The most direct translation of the C# code only generates a single random index and then uses that in place of the `random.Next(s.Length)`. But I need to generate multiple indexes, not a single one.

Then I considered doing a list of `IO Int` random number actions, but I can't work out how to go through and convert the list of `IO` actions into actual random numbers.

So the Haskell code that I end up writing ends up looking quite convoluted compared to the C# (which I wasn't expecting in this case) and I haven't even got it to work anyway.

My question, what would be a natural translation of the C# to Haskell? Or more generally, how would you go about generating a random String of a specified length in Haskell (because this C# way doesn't seem to translate well to Haskell)?

Note: I'm mainly interested in what the algorithm to generate a random string looks like in Haskell. I'm not really interested in any standard libraries which do the job for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The natural translation to Haskell involves having some sort of `IO` (as you need randomness). Since you are essentially trying to perform the action of choosing a character `n` times, you want to use [`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM). Then, for getting a random number in a range, you can use [`randomRIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomRIO).

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.Random (randomRIO)

randomString :: Int -> IO String
randomString n = replicateM n (do r <- randomRIO (0,m); pure (chars !! r))
  where
    chars = ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0'..'9']
    m = length chars
```

This is somewhat complicated by the fact you want a string of only characters in a certain range. otherwise, you'd have a one liner: `randomString n = replicateM n randomIO`.

---

That said, the more faithful translation would use [`conduit`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.10/conduit-combinators-1.0.8.2/Data-Conduit-Combinators.html). I'm not going to include imports and language pragmas (because they are a bit painful). This looks a lot more like what you would write in C#:

```
randomString' :: Int -> IO String
randomString' n = runConduit $ replicate n chars
                            .| mapM (\cs -> do r <- randomRIO (0,m); pure (cs !! r))
                            .| sinkList
  where
    chars = ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0'..'9']
    m = length chars
```